# How can I separate a string with a ForLoop and the == operator?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, substring

This class assignment is designed to teach us to use the for loop to separate and compare substrings

```
s = '456+123'                 # separate the two strings, convert them to int and add them

for char in range(0,len(s)-1): # use the for loop 
   if '+' == str(char):        # string comparison
      substring1 = s[0:char]   # slice 1st string
      substring2 = s[char + 1:len(s)-1] # slice second string

      print(substring1)
      print(substring2)
else:
   print('Cannot separate the string')
```

** Spoiler Alert for CSC Waterloo (online) students! **
...Thanks for the answers... Here is the correct code I used for the assignment

```
s = '123+456'
for char in range(0,len(s)-1):
if s[char] == '+':
    substring1 = int(s[0:char])
    substring2 = int(s[char:len(s)])
    print(substring1 + substring2)
```

Comment: It's an assignment? And what have you done so far to solve it? What are the results?

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is with the code you've posted, or asked a clear question. Can you please [edit] to do both? Thanks.

Comment: Homework doesn't belong on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop doesn't work because `char` is not a character in `s` but an integer in the range from 0 (inclusive) to length-of-`s`-minus-one (exclusive).

I'd *split* the input string:

```
value1, value2 = s.split('+')
result = int(value1) + int(value2)
```

If you **have** to use a `for` loop, then take into account you are looping over an index, retrieve the original character with indexing:

```
for i in range(len(s)):
    if s[i] == '+':
        value1 = s[:i]
        value2 = s[i + 1:]
        break
else:
    print('Cannot separate the string')
```

but even then you could use `str.find()` instead:

```
index = s.find('+')
if index > -1:
    value1 = s[:i]
    value2 = s[i + 1:]
else:
    print('Cannot separate the string')
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your question is "why doesn't this work?":

1. `for char in range(0,len(s)-1):` gives you indices within `s` assigned to `char`, not the characters themselves. Therefore your comparison should be `if '+' == s[char]:`;
2. In the `for: else:` syntax, the `else` clause occurs unless the loop `break`s or `return`s, so will always run in your code; and
3. You never actually use `int()` and carry out the addition.